# Can't print newline to shell correctly? python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I have the following problem: This returns "\n" in the output, but I want it to return a newline like an SQL query, can anyone help me with this?
IDLE, Python 2.7.5.

`int iD, str days, int maxCapacity, int crn, int enrollment, string semester, string room`

python code:

```
def registerCourse(iD, days, maxCapacity, crn, enrollment, semester, room):
    return "UPDATE CoursesOffered" + "\n" + "SET InstructorID=" + str(iD) + ",Days=" + str(days) + ",MaxCapacity=" + str(maxCapacity) + ",Enrollment=" + str(enrollment) + "\n" + "WHERE CRN=" + str(crn)
```

I guess the real question is: How do I get this in the string format and return it? I am trying to get this to be a directly executed SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

"\n" is just a representation of a newline.

```
>>> a = 'a\nb'   
>>> a
'a\nb'
>>> print (a)
a
b
```

Try passing the value to the `print` function (or statement in py2, but the parentheses never hurt).

**NOTA BENE**

If possible, restrain from using string-functions to pass parameters to a query. This opens all doors for SQL-injection and weakens the veil between our world and the nether realms, arosing HIM who waits behind the wall. Pass your parameters through the driver.

For example, what happens if `crn` equals `'1 or true'`, or if it equals `'1;drop table CoursesOffered'`.

Answer (score 0):

That function returns a string. If you print the string, it will render with a new line. For example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return "Hi \n This is on a new line."
...
>>> foo()
'Hi \n This is on a new line.'
>>> print foo()
Hi
 This is on a new line.
```